# Singular interval condition for Multi input in Optimal control

Tags: control, control-system, math, optimization

The definition of singulr interval is shown in Figure.
[image]
I've struggled with this problem.
[image]
I think the solution of this prob
is "because if the E_j matrix is not singular, it means the System is controllable, so it doesn't have singular interval...
But I want to know the details of the solution,"the precise answer" of this problem.

Please help me to escape this prob:(

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*because if the \$E_j\$ matrix is not singular, it means the System is controllable*". Controllable if the input \$j\$ **alone** is considered. The system can be controllable even if \$E_j\$ is singular for any one value of \$j\$ if \$E_j\$ is non singular for some other value of \$j\$.

Comment: Please provide the definition of "*singular interval*".

Comment: @AJN Sorry, I put the def of singular interval.

Answer (score 0):

## 1st interpretation of singular interval

"[A singular interval is] where Pontryagin's principle provides no information regarding u in terms of x, p and t."

You have a minimum-time optimal control which I assume is stated as:
$$ 
\min_{\|u\|_\infty \leq 1} t_f \\
\text{s.t.} \quad \dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)\\
 x(0) = 0, \quad
 x(t_f) = x_t\\
 0\leq t_f.
$$
And I assume that the pre-Hamiltonian is
$$ H(t,x,p,u) = -p^\top (Ax+Bu),$$
and that you have a costate \$p^*\$ that is not identically zero and evolves as:
$$ \dot{p}^*(t) = -A^\top p^*(t).$$

Your definition seems to mean that in a singular interval any feasible \$u\$ will be the optimal control with the same value for \$H(t,x^*,p^*,u^*)=H(t,x^*,p^*,u)\$, therefore any feasible \$u\$ will have:

$$ 0 = {p^*}^\top B u $$

And you can show that if any \${p^*}^\top B u \$ is nonzero then you would have some information on \$u\$, i.e. the optimal \$u\$ would be at the boundary of \$ \{u : \|u\|_\infty \leq 1\}\$ and in certain direction(s). So:
$$ 0 = {p^*}^\top B u, \, \forall u  \Leftrightarrow {p^*}^\top B =0,$$
And since \$p^*\$  is differentiable we have:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)^k {p^*}^\top B = {p^*}^\top (-A)^k B=0, $$
which gives us that:

$$ {p^*}^\top \left[ B, AB, A^2B \dots A^nB \right] = 0$$
meaning that the controlability matrix is rank deficient. Somehow I got a stronger result than what the problem asks, there is probably something wrong with my proof and it is probably that definition of singular control, where Pontryagin's  principle provides **no information** regarding u in terms of x, p and t.

## 2nd interpretation of singular interval

I decide to interpret that a singular interval is one where Pontryagin's principle does not provide a unique \$u\$ in terms of \$x\$, \$p\$ and \$t\$. That would meant that we can have two (or more) optimal values for \$u\$, let them be \$\tilde{u}, \hat{u}\$. Since we have the constraint \$\|u\|_\infty \leq 1\$ and the cost function is linear we have that the minima of the cost will be achieved at the [vertices of the polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Theory).
And
$$ \tilde{u}, \hat{u} \in \{-1,1\}^m. $$
And we can even construct such optima, to determine the components \$\hat{u}_i\$ or \$\tilde{u}\$ we do
$$
 \nabla_u (-p^\top B u) = -B^\top p,\\
 \hat{u}_i = \begin{cases} -1,\quad (-B^\top p)_{i,:} > 0 \\ 1,\quad (-B^\top p)_{i,:} < 0 \\ ?,\quad (-B^\top p)_{i,:} = 0 \end{cases}
$$
where \$ (A)_{i,:}\$ means the i-th row of A and \$ (A)_{:,i}\$ means the i-th column.

Since we have at least two different optima \$\tilde{u}\$ and \$\hat{u}\$ they can only be different in components \$i\$ with \$(-B^\top p)_{i,:} = 0\$, and there is at least one such \$i\$. Then you have

$$ (-B^\top p)_{i,:} = 0 = -(B^\top)_{i,:} p = -p^\top (B)_{:,i} $$

Denoting the i-th column of \$B\$ as \$(B)_{:,i}=b_i\$ we can clearly see that
$$ -p^\top b_i = 0 $$
and due to \$p\$ being differentiable we get that:

$$ -p^\top (-A)^k b_i = 0 $$

and

$$ p^\top [ b_i, A b_i, A^2 b_i, \dots ] = 0. $$

Which means that \$E_i\$ (as defined in your question) will be singular.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) But I know that your answer is general proof for B is vector, not matrix. I want to know when the B is Matrix not a vector(you know, it means Multi input), how can I prove that the system have singular intervals if the Controllability matrix E_j is singular about "at least" singular value of j(Column of B). I think "at least" should be focused in this problem. And I think the solution should be expanded from your answer.

Comment: That's the thing, I did include in my answer that "Somehow I got a stronger result than what the problem asks, there is probably something wrong with my proof and it is probably that definition of singular control, where Pontryagin's principle provides no information regarding u in terms of x, p and t." By strong I mean that the whole controllability matrix is rank deficient, not matrix E_j for some j. And yes, my answer works for a matrix B, I never assumed it to be a vector.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the definition of "[in the interval in which the pre-Hamiltonian] provides no relationship between u, x and p [the problem is singular and the interval is a singular interval]"? What does it mean to provide no information?

Comment: I appreciate to your answer! I You mean...thus, if there is rank deficient about "at least" any j, the whole rank controllability matrix is deficient, that is, it means there have singular intervals..right? Then...Can I ask that if there is rank deficient about "at least" any B column j(B is matrix),the whole controllability matrix has rank deficient. I've tried searching this theorem, but I couldnt find that for Matrix B(multi input). Can I get some explanations or links for this theorem please? Thanks for your caring reply again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but having some rank deficient E_j for some j **does not** mean the controllability matrix is rank deficient. But having the controllability matrix being rank deficient means every E_j is rank deficient.

Comment: Please, add to your question what does it mean by the pre-Hamiltonian provides no information on what is the optimal u. I am pretty sure that that is the main catch of that exercise.